# Add minor tick marks to Bayesian change point plot

Tags: r, plot, axis, bayesian, x-axis

I have drawn a plot using the Bayesian change point, and I need to add a minor tickmark to the x-axis. Can anyone help me?
Here are my codes:

```
df<-read.csv("Temp.csv")  
x <- df.ts  
bcp_x <- bcp(x, return.mcmc = TRUE)  
plot(bcp_x)
```

[[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look how to make a great [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. include the output of `dput` of your example data and all packages you use. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: After calling the `plot` function you can add ticks like this `rug(x = 0:50 + 0.5, ticksize = -0.01, side = 1)`